# How to convert text file to xml in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I have a big text file that I want to convert into Xcode. I added the text file in the main bundle (drag and drop) into my project . I can see the text file `viewDidLoad`.
But I like to convert it to XML file. For instance my file looks like :

```
  asasasasasas          
  wewewewewewe        
  qwqwqwqwqwqw
xyz_ 22 aaaaaaaaaaa        
fgfgfgfgfgfgfg        
ererererererer

abc_ 12 bbbbbbbbbb       
jkjkjkjkjkjkjk     
lalallalalalal
```

In the above mentioned, I want to eliminate the first 3 lines, to start from `xyz_ 22` as (parent), `jkjkjkj` as child `lalalala` as a child.

I need only the idea how to implement this ... I'll write the code :)

mycode:
- (IBAction)readUsingObjectiveC:(id)pId {
    NSString * zStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/dd007/Desktop/abc.txt" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"readUsingObjectiveC zStr=\n%@",zStr);

```
// now to extract the data line by line
NSArray * zAryOfLines = [zStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
if([zAryOfLines count] == 0) 
{
    NSLog(@"readUsingObjectiveC zAryOfLines count = 0");
    return;
} 
//for (int i=0; i<([zAryOfLines count]-30); ++i)
for ( int i=30; i<zAryOfLines ; i++)  

{
         if([[zAryOfLines objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"xyz_ "])
         {
             NSLog(@"<msg1>%@<msg1/>\n",[zAryOfLines objectAtIndex:i]);
             NSLog(@"<msg2>%@<msg2/>\n",[zAryOfLines objectAtIndex:i+1]);
             NSLog(@"<msg3>%@<msg3/>\n",[zAryOfLines objectAtIndex:i+2]);
[zArrayOfLines writeToFIle:@"/.....documents/..save.xml" automatically:YES encodingNSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];             
         }
     }
```

I am getting convert into xml format but i like to save the file in .xml .. but i am getting error could any one tell me where i am doing mistake ??????

Comment: i suppose ..firstly you would need to extract the contents of text file into a NSString

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a file to xml using XCode, you have two options:

You can create a python or ruby script that parses your file and makes a XML file, and then use a xml parser,

Or you can create a class that parses your plain file with the rules you want.

Comment: i had the same idea to implement what you mentioned in the second option .... then i have to read each line and have to make a xml tag for body , parent , child ... is it i am right ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to transform a .txt to a .xml so for make this i read the .txt to a nsstring i cut this into a NSArray with componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n" method of NSString (take care of \r character) and after just don't take line you don't want and create a new NSString for add tag XML to your line if you now where place the good tag or check it with the contains of your line in the NSArray for finish just saved in new file with extension .xml.

If you need help for write code like i describe say it.

Comment: @ user1770436 thanks for your  idea its amazing ... i like it ... if u have some example code ... i love it :) because it will reduce my work.. once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for converting the text to xml directly in iOS.
But you can do it by passing the data manually.

You can use either `libXml` framework or `GDataXml` for doing this.

For `libXml` xml generation sample code go to this [**link**](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-iPhone-and-iPad-Database-Application-Programming.productCd-0470636173,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) and download Chapter 10.zip

Please check this tutorial for [Read and Write XML Documents with GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

Also [TCMXMLWriter](https://github.com/monkeydom/TCMXMLWriter) is an opensource xmlgenerator :

Answer (score 0):

I think a code like this work for your example :

```
NSString *contentFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *lineFile = [contentFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableString *xmlFile = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
For(int i = 3; i < lineFile.count; i++)//i = 3 for don't take the 3 first line
{
    if ([((NSString *)[lineFile objectAtIndex:i]) rangedOfString:@"test"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        xmlFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<nameTag>%@</nameTag>", xmlFile, (NSString *)[lineFile objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else if ...
}
```

And save he nsstring in new file. Possible in loop to make by number like if i is multiple of 3 of 4 etc...

Comment: Its not working i tried making text to string to array and making tag for the specific char... but its not converting to xml format ..

Comment: [xmlFile writeToFile:@/....documents..xml" automatically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:Null]


wow its working fine :) thanks pal